# ASP.Net C# POST not returning view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post

Using ASP.NET, C# and Javascript, I'm trying to dynamically get Data for the user, POST it to a controller, and return a view that changes depending on the Data.

Here's the code :

Javascript function :

```
function editEntry(id) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "Edit?id=" + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send({ id: id });
    //xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Controller handling post (a portion) :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditEvenementiel edit)
{
    var contexte = new intranetEntities1();                       

    SqlParameter Id_viewBag = new SqlParameter("@id", edit.id);
    ViewBag.edit = contexte.evenementiel
       .SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM evenementiel WHERE id_evenementiel = @id", Id_viewBag);

    return View();
}
```

when i fire the javascript, i can see the POST in the firebug console (working fine), i can see the variable getting the correct value in Visual Studio's Debugger, but the view doesn't change.

I even see the expected view (with all the treatements expected) returned in the firebug console; but my page still doesn't change.

How can i do that ?

Comment: You cannot use the ViewBag data like that.You are setting it to ViewBag. You need to execute some razor code to read that. You better return the value as JSON

Comment: i didn't showed it, but the ViewBag is properly processed in the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you should have 2 `Actions`, one that should process/get the data through a `Post` method and one that collects data for the `View`. (it's called Post/Redirect/Get - more details on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get))

Having this in mind, you can leave your post method as :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var contexte = new intranetEntities1();
        SqlParameter Id_viewBag = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
        EditEvenementiel edit = contexte.evenementiel.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM evenementiel WHERE id_evenementiel = @id", Id_viewBag);

        return RedirectToAction("Edit",new { edit = edit} );
    }
```

and create a new action which sends the data to the view.

Something like:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(EditEvenementiel edit)
    {
       //logic here
        return View(edit);
    }
```

Please be aware that `this is just an example`, modify it according to your scenario.

Comment: thank you very much, you exactly got what i was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Ajax (XMLHttpRequest) to fetch this data you also need to present it on your page, it wont happen automatically.

Maybe something like this?

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // or put the responseText in a HTML element of your choice to do whatever you want to do

    }
}
```

Comment: you know, i expect the controller to redirect me to the View "Edit", like with the different url

Comment: maybe you should just skip the whole Ajax thing and do a normal GET with a id and load your item based on that.  [HttpGet] and ActionResult Edit(int id) and then just link to that view instead like /mycontroller/edit/:editid:

Answer (score 0):

Where do you actually *update* anything on the page?  All you do is send the request:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "Edit?id=" + id, true);
xmlhttp.send({ id: id });
```

But you ignore the response.  The browser isn't going to know what you want to do with that response, you have to tell it.  Which could be something as simple as:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById('someElement').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
```

Basically, use the AJAX response (which is an HTML view?) to update the page content.

Comment: how do i get this response as a page ? you know, i'd expect the url to change and the page as well, since the response is the whole html page i was expecting

Comment: @Orsu: What do you mean by "get the response as a page"?  If you want to actually navigate to a new page then you don't want to use AJAX.  I'm not sure why you would expect the URL to change or for anything to happen in response to an AJAX call.  You're seeing the response in your browser's debugging tools, right?  That response is available to your JavaScript code to do whatever you like with it.

Comment: i used your solution, it will be fine. To explain, i was just trying to ONLY send data to the controller, who'd process it, and return a new page where i'd go, like it was a link or something

Comment: @Orsu: `"return a new page where i'd go"` - That sounds like navigation, which isn't AJAX.  It sounds like what you want is simply a link or a `form`.  Using JavaScript at all seems to be unnecessarily complicating the issue.